# Relationship "doesntHave" doesnt work in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I need help. I have a problem. In this part of the code Relationship "doesntHave" doesnt work and return full list of the users

```
$searchData = $request->searchData;
$users = User::doesntHave('roles')
    ->where('id','like', '%' . $searchData . '%')
    ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $searchData . '%')
    ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $searchData . '%')
    ->limit(8)
    ->get();
       
return response()->json($users);
```

Comment: If you inspect the final query - replace `get()` with `toSql()`, or use something like https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar, you'll likely find that your query is something like `WHERE <doesn't have roles> AND id LIKE foo OR name LIKE foo OR email LIKE foo` and that your three `where` clauses should be within parentheses, because the ORs apply to *everything* in the query.

Comment: How you define `roles` function on User model?

Answer (score 0):

The priority of AND and OR operators is the same so `a AND b OR c OR d` is essentially the same as `(((a AND b) OR C) or D)`. In your case you probably want `a AND (b OR c OR d)` so to achieve this you need:

```
$searchData = $request->searchData;
$users = User::doesntHave('roles')
    ->where(function ($q) use ($searchData) {
        $q->where('id','like', '%' . $searchData . '%')
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $searchData . '%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $searchData . '%');
    })
    ->limit(8)
    ->get();
       
return response()->json($users);
```

Comment: $searchData = $request->searchData;
$users = User::doesntHave('roles')->where(function ($q) use ($searchData) {
          $q->where('id','like', '%' . $searchData . '%')
          ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $searchData . '%')
         ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $searchData . '%');
          })->limit(8)
          ->get();